# A path optimisation problem

Tags: pr.probability, graph-theory, oc.optimization-and-control

Consider a graph of $n$ nodes randomly located in $[0,1]^2$. Each node moves following a path randomly chosen from the set of all possible paths. Regard nodes as attackers. A policeman seeks an optimum path $P$ of length no more than $L$ between two points $s$ and $t$ and aims at catching the maximum number of attackers along $P$. The problem is to calculate the maximum expected number of attackers caught by the policeman (assymptotically).

Comment: I find some parts of your question difficult to understand. Can you elaborate on the part where the paths are "randomly chosen from the set of all possible paths"? Do you have some sort of random walk in mind?
Also, how does the graph relate to the nodes lying in the unit square?

Comment: @monkeymaths. Thx monkeymath, a path can be any curve. The graph is composed of nodes randomly distributed in $[0,1]^2$.